# CKeditor protectedSource handlebars

Tags: ckeditor

I am attempting to use CKeditor with handlebar templates to allow users to customize messages in our app.

CKEditor does some weird stuff

It turns this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Activity</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Amount</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{line_items}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Into this:

```
{{line_items}}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Activity</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Rate</td>
      <td>Amount</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Then googling led me to use `config.protectedSource` to protect all handlebars.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('template_body', {
  //... other stuff

  protectedSource: [
    /{{[\s\S]*?}}/g
  ]
}
```

This setting does properly protect handlebar tags from being moved and removed, but then prevents them from being viewed/edited!

CKEditor hides the protected source while in editing mode, and shows it while in source mode! is that a bug? I can see `{{}}` while in source mode of the editor but not in regular mode?

Comment: Hey Blair, were you ever able to figure out a decent solution to this? I'm in the same boat...

Comment: @jetcom using `protectedSource: []` was the best solution we came up with. Its only painful when the HTML is not semantic. Its tough when you want to let your users include variables... shrug

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the number for requests it looks like the author of [this plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/showprotected) did a great work, try it. You shall be able to edit protected source in wysiwyg mode with it.